# How to highlight text in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I thought this would be easier to find because it seems to be such a common functionality (i.e. text editors), but I am making a web app in Flask. Basically, the client submits a string; python finds any errors and highlights them and then returns it to the client. When the client changes that mistake, the highlight goes away.

I've already figured out how to return the mistake, but I don't know how to return highlighted texts. I've heard about the Curses library, but to be honest, I find it to be a bit intimidating.
What do you think is the easiest implementation for this quandary?

Comment: `<span class="highlighted">text</span>` and a bit of CSS.

Comment: check `mark` tag https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_mark.asp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question can be somewhat subjective and lead to many different answers. Try to bring some context by providing some examples and sharing some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you at @Epsi95. I think your answer was the simplest. The purpose of my question was to be subjective, so I could learn about various solutions. There doesn't seem to be any answers on this area in python (that are clean or convenient), but now I know how to accomplish this task using both html and python in Flask.

For anyone who is interested, this is how I used it in Flask, where python indicates the character error and html highlights it for the user. In python:

```
    def find_error(text):
        # Let's say that user entered 'some string!.'
        error='!.'
        indices=[]
        idx = -1
        while True:
            idx = text.find(error, idx+1)
            if idx == -1:
                break
            indices.append(idx)
            yield idx
        return render_template("index.html",text=text,indices=indices)
```

And in html:

```
    {% block content}
    <input type="hidden" value={{indices}}/>
    <textarea style="overflow-y: scroll;">
    {{text}}
    {% for index in indices%}
    {% loc=text[index:index+2]%}
    <mark style="background-color: yellow;">{{loc}}</mark>
    {%endfor%}
    </textarea>
    {% endblock %}
```

Because the error was unlikely to be intended, the highlight will go away upon editing. If someone knows a better way, please let me know.